# How to create a menu like the image

Tags: java, swing, menu, jbutton

I want to create a menu, like this image : [image]

It's a sort of button, when the user clicks in that button a menu appears, with diffrent options. Also, when the user choses one of those option,another submenu appears, Just as is shown the image.
I don't know witch class i need , In order to accomplish this task.

Comment: You might consider creating a button and then displaying a [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) when pressed.